# Error while downloading file from PHPExcel due to bad encoding

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

I have a problem with the PHPExcel library, it is generating the file correctly and saving on the server, however it is not downloading any way directly on the site and it appears bad encoding, this started to cause after the server change.
I have already changed some headers but with no success.
I am using Excel5 with the xls extension

```
    public function export(){
    $dir = "download";
    $dh  = opendir($dir);
    $now = new DateTime();
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))){
        if(preg_match("/^filiadas\-[nacional|ac|al|am|ap|ba|ce|df|es|go|ma|mg|ms|mt|pa|pb|pe|pi|pr|rj|rn|ro|rr|rs|sc|sp|to].*\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\.xls$/", $filename, $matches)){
            //exclui arquivo criado a mais de 12 horas atrás
            if(($now->getTimestamp() - filemtime($dir . "/" . $filename))>(60*60*12)){
                $path_file = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . "/download/" . $filename;

                if(file_exists($path_file)){
                    unlink($path_file);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');



    $data = array();
    $fields = $this->filiadas->getFields();
    $options = $this->filiadas->getOptions();
    if(isset($_GET["unidas_uf"])){
        $this->filiadas->setData(
            array("unidas_uf" => strtoupper($_GET["unidas_uf"]))
        );
    }

    $this->filiadas->get();
    $this->aObjData->filiadas = $this->filiadas->get();

    //load our new PHPExcel library
    $this->load->library('excel');
    //activate worksheet number 1
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    //name the worksheet
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Filiadas');
    //set cell A1 content with some text
    //$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Filiadas');
    //change the font size
    //$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setSize(20);
    //make the font become bold
    //$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    //merge cell A1 until D1
    //$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:AD1');

    //$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

    $pColumn=0;
    $pRow=1;

    foreach($fields as $field){

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($pColumn,$pRow,$field);
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimensionByColumn($pColumn)->setAutoSize(true);

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyleByColumnAndRow( $pColumn, $pRow )->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $pColumn++;
    }

    //$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($this->aObjData->filiadas, ' ', 'A2');
    foreach( $this->aObjData->filiadas as $filiada ){
        $pColumn=0;
        $pRow++;
        //$aFiliada = "";//get_object_vars($filiada);

        //nat_juridica_sub
        if ( array_key_exists( $filiada[ 'nat_juridica_sub' ], $options[ 'nat_juridica_sub1' ] ) )
            $filiada[ 'nat_juridica_sub' ] = $options[ 'nat_juridica_sub1' ][ $filiada[ 'nat_juridica_sub' ] ];
        else if ( array_key_exists( $filiada[ 'nat_juridica_sub' ], $options[ 'nat_juridica_sub2' ] ) )
            $filiada[ 'nat_juridica_sub' ] = $options[ 'nat_juridica_sub2' ][ $filiada[ 'nat_juridica_sub' ] ];

        //nat_juridica
        if( isset( $filiada[ 'nat_juridica' ] ) && array_key_exists( $filiada[ 'nat_juridica' ], $options[ 'nat_juridica' ] ) )
            $filiada[ 'nat_juridica' ] = $options[ 'nat_juridica' ][ $filiada[ 'nat_juridica' ] ];

        //tipo_plano
        if( isset( $filiada[ 'tipo_plano' ] ) && array_key_exists( $filiada[ 'tipo_plano' ], $options[ 'tipo_plano' ] ) )
            $filiada[ 'tipo_plano' ] = $options[ 'tipo_plano' ][ $filiada[ 'tipo_plano' ] ];

        //segmento
        if( isset( $filiada[ 'segmento' ] ) && array_key_exists( $filiada[ 'segmento' ], $options[ 'segmento' ] ) )
            $filiada[ 'segmento' ] = $options[ 'segmento' ][ $filiada[ 'segmento' ] ];

        //especie
        if( isset( $filiada[ 'especie' ] ) && array_key_exists( $filiada[ 'especie' ], $options[ 'especie' ] ) )
            $filiada[ 'especie' ] = $options[ 'especie' ][ $filiada[ 'especie' ] ];

        //rede_credenciada
        if( isset( $filiada[ 'rede_credenciada' ] ) )
        {
            $rede_credenciada = '';
            $indexes = explode( ',', $filiada[ 'rede_credenciada' ]);
            foreach($indexes as $index)
            {
                if ( array_key_exists( $index, $options[ 'rede_credenciada' ] ) )
                $rede_credenciada.= $options[ 'rede_credenciada' ][ $index ] . ',';
            }
            $filiada[ 'rede_credenciada' ] = trim($rede_credenciada, ",");
        }
        //custeio
        if( isset( $filiada[ 'custeio' ] ) )
        {
            $custeio = '';
            $indexes = explode( ',', $filiada[ 'custeio' ]);
            foreach($indexes as $index)
            {
                if ( array_key_exists( $index, $options[ 'custeio' ] ) )
                $custeio.= $options[ 'custeio' ][ $index ] . ',';
            }
            $filiada[ 'custeio' ] = trim($custeio, ",");
        }

        //contribuicao
        if( isset( $filiada[ 'contribuicao' ] ) )
        {
            $contribuicao = '';
            $indexes = explode( ',', $filiada[ 'contribuicao' ]);
            foreach($indexes as $index)
            {
                if ( array_key_exists( $index, $options[ 'contribuicao' ] ) )
                $contribuicao.= $options[ 'contribuicao' ][ $index ] . ',';
            }
            $filiada[ 'contribuicao' ] = trim($contribuicao, ",");
        }


        foreach($fields as $field){
            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($pColumn,$pRow,$filiada[$field]);

            if(!empty($filiada["filiada_data_desfiliacao"]) && $filiada["filiada_data_desfiliacao"]!="0000-00-00"){
                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyleByColumnAndRow($pColumn,$pRow)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('FF9999');
            }

            $pColumn++;
        }

    }

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->calculateColumnWidths();


    $filename = "filiadas-" . (isset($_GET["unidas_uf"])?(empty($_GET["unidas_uf"])?"nacional":strtolower($_GET["unidas_uf"]))."-":"") . date("Y-m-d"). ".xls"; //save our workbook as this file name
    //save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
    //if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save("download/".$filename);
    //$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->unfreezePane();
    //force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
    //$objWriter->save('php://output');

    /*
    $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
    $cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize' => '8MB');

    if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod,$cacheSettings))
    die('CACHEING ERROR');
    */

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
    readfile("download/".$filename);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: does the excel file exist in the directory?When you go to the actual directory and manually download it, does it work?

Comment: are there any outputs before you set the headers?

Comment: @Ibu Yes, the file is in the download directory, and I can finish downloading normally through the cpanel.

Comment: Give readfile an absolute path, and make sure that no other content is being printed on the page.

Comment: @ibu, When I remove the readfile the page gets all white but does not download.

Comment: Turn on errors by adding `ini_set("display_errors","On");` in the beginning of your code.

Comment: so your script does it job as it is on the old server, but not on the new one ? do you checked the encoding of your .php files ?

Answer (score 0):

Just Use ob_end_clean() before $objWriter->save("download/".$filename);

like

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save("download/".$filename);
```